# Sharepoint 2010/2013 Document Library - Document Versioning

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary, document-versioning

Can we control versions of the documents stored in the library like setting the beginning base version and ignore versioning on certain check-in/check-outs/modifications of a document ?

We are accessing this document library in our application through the client object model. But our legacy application requires a more control over the versions of the documents which are going to be stored in sharepoint and at the same time we would like to leverage the sharepoint document library's versioning features too. How do we achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that using event receiver. 
You could have a field named "proposed version" and the event receiver would set it to that. You can hide/making it readonly/set it in pages like viewitem.aspx using jquery.